# Is less interpreted by the browser like CSS?

Tags: html, css, less

There's an example [here](http://semantic.gs/examples/responsive/responsive.html) in which there is a stylesheet of type `text/less` that is interpreted by google chrome, but appears to have nothing but less syntax in it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.less" type="text/less" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example also calls `<script src="../../js/less-1.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Here `less-1.1.3.min.js` compiles the less from responsive.less to css and return it back to the browser. Also see: http://lesscss.org/#usage

See below you will find the client side compiled CSS between `<style id="less:examples-responsive-responsive" type="text/css" media="screen">`:

[image]

Comment: So it's Javascript based...ah ha!  But isn't it also possible that we can compile less into CSS on the serverside (or precompile it for use later?)  It seems to me that using less this way could cause an accessibility issue.

Comment: @leeand00 yes in fact that is the prefered solution

Comment: @kleinfreund http://twitterbootstrap3buttons.w3masters.nl/ as an example of "live" server generated less

Comment: @leeand00: yes, LESS can also be dynamically compiled in the server or more commonly precompiled in the developers' machine before deploying to the server.

Answer (score 1):

No, no browsers interprets LESS directly. The page must have contained less.js, which is a JavaScript  implementation of a LESS compiler.

Answer (score 1):

LESS is a dynamic stylesheet compiled by `less.js` (or in the example given, less-1.1.3.min.js), producing normal CSS once complete. The browser doesn't understand the LESS file itself.

LESS can also be used server-side, as described [on the LESS website](http://lesscss.org/#usage).

```
$ npm install -g less
```

Answer (score 1):

LESS files (just like sass files) will always need to be parsed and compiled by a CSS preprocessor. From my experience it's preferable to precompile all your css files beforehand.

By all means avoid using the javascript library in combination with less files in a production environment, because it will affect the performance of the client's browser. Certainly when it comes to mobile devices.

For Windows I have used Winless which would compile my LESS files on change (www.winless.org)

About a year ago I started using ZURB Foundation and therefore switched to SASS CSS. It is very similar to LESSCSS and I like it very much because it's more robust and modular. But that's a personal opinion...